# Android Application: Background stretching

Tags: android, eclipse, background, scrollview

In my eclipse, when ever I have a scrollView and a background image set up at the same time, my background image stretches vertically. I would like it not to stretch but repeat all the way down the ScrollView.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Create a XML file within the drawable:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image" 
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

than you can use this file as your drawable, and it will be repeated

Note that there is a bug related to repeat (android 3.0 and bellow), when used in a listview
see [XML drawable Bitmap tileMode bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586209/xml-drawable-bitmap-tilemode-bug)

Comment: I must have done something wrong? did you tried to change the selector? or set it to draw on top?